# Where should my character be at before jumping into Dragon Age Inquisition: Jaws of Hakkon

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I've got a post-20 character, and I've beaten Corypheus and most of the High Dragons (I think I have one or two left). When I first started poking around the new content, I quickly found that the groups of mobs were of much higher difficulty than in the other zones. I'm guessing it's aimed at people who have finished most, if not all, the previous content... and I've still got several zones to complete. I focused more on the main storyline vs a completionist play.

What would you recommend I focus on in terms of gear before I head back into the fray? Most of the reviews just say post-20 but don't really go into a lot more detail than that, and it doesn't seem to be that simple to me. I guess I'm just looking for objectives that I can focus on completing so that when I go back into it, I don't feel like I'm wasting my time fighting things that are harder than they should be because I wasn't prepared enough.

Thanks!

Comment: Great question! I changed the title to reflect your question, rather then the game your playing. This will present what your asking to users that are just scrolling through the list of questions. Might get you a bit more traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to define a concrete minimum requirement to play Jaws of Hakkon, because it varies a lot based on your party composition, playstyle, difficulty, and so on.

Once your party reaches a level range where you're comfortable taking on level 20 enemies, is when you should be able to complete Jaws of Hakkon. In terms of goals, this is hard to define: if you're focusing on just following the main story rather than full completionist playstyle, this will be around the end of the base game.

Most reviews/guides recommend 'post-20', which is a good guess for the average playthrough. Meaning, you should have finished most of the base content, be at or near the final boss, and be confident enough to defeat level 20 enemies. This doesn't necessarily mean you should be level 20, though, as this could be much earlier.

On a normal playthrough, I was able to complete most of Jaws of Hakkon with a party around level 15, though this was pretty challenging at times.

Finally, I'd also recommend doing it before the final story choices, because (warning: spoiler)

> it's possible that these choices affect your available companions

Comment: Hm, ok. I'm currently 22 (IIRC, possibly higher), but I found it to be overly difficult when I last tried. Not sure if there's better gear than what I have that I should be crafting. I tend to run around with Dorian/Vivienne/Iron Bull. I already beat Corypheus some time back on this playthrough, so Solas is gone. (I respecced Viv to handle the healing.)

Comment: Do you have any recommendations for what kind of gear I should be using, or a site that documents what crafting recipes are available so I can see how what I'm currently using stacks up? Thanks.

Comment: well thought out answer, but I feel if OPs main issue is that they are 20+ and it is too difficult, "Being 20+" is ultimately not going to answer their question.

Comment: When did you last try it? Were you already past level 20 when you did? Have you recently tried it again? It sounds like you gave it a shot a while ago, but haven't tried since because you think it might be too difficult still. I'm not sure of a comprehensive guide/website that lists all crafted gear, but here's [a list of the best (crafted) weapons from Black Emporium/Jaws of Hakkon](http://dragoninquisition.com/guide-best-weapons/).

Comment: Thanks, granted the bounty for the follow-up which has some concrete data I could examine... I realized the original question was too hard to answer, but you did help... thanks.